# wso2 apim IsAuthReqSigned has no effect

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Using WSO2AM 2.1.0 trying to configure SAML IdP using a file deployment. The issue is I am unable to make the SAML request signed (required by the IdP).

I assumed that the parameter `IsAuthReqSigned` should enable signing the SAML Request, but apparently it is not (HTTP-Redirect binding is used and there's no signature between the parameters)

having following IdP configuration (certificate and real names are blanked out):

```
<IdentityProvider>
    <IdentityProviderName>oamidp</IdentityProviderName>
    <DisplayName>oamidp</DisplayName>
    <IdentityProviderDescription>Ext Access Manager</IdentityProviderDescription>
    <Alias>oamidp</Alias>
    <IsPrimary/>
    <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
    <IsFederationHub/>
    <HomeRealmId/>
    <ProvisioningRole/>
    <FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
            <saml2>
                    <Name>SAMLSSOAuthenticator</Name>
                    <DisplayName>samlsso</DisplayName>
                    <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
                    <Properties>
                        <property>
                                <Name>IdpEntityId</Name>
                                <Value>https://logon-test.xxx.com/oam/fed</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>IsLogoutEnabled</Name>
                                <Value>true</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>SPEntityId</Name>
                                <Value>https://wso2am-test/sp</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>SSOUrl</Name>
                                <Value>https://logon-test.xxx.com/oamfed/idp/samlv20</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>isAssertionSigned</Name>
                                <Value>false</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>commonAuthQueryParams</Name>
                                <Value></Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>IsUserIdInClaims</Name>
                                <Value>true</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>IsLogoutReqSigned</Name>
                                <Value>false</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>IsAssertionEncrypted</Name>
                                <Value>false</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>IsAuthReqSigned</Name>
                                <Value>true</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>IsAuthnRespSigned</Name>
                                <Value>true</Value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                                <Name>LogoutReqUrl</Name>
                                <Value>https://logon-test.portofantwerp.com/oamfed/idp/samlv20</Value>
                                <!-- Value>false</Value -->
                        </property>
                </Properties>
            </saml2>
    </FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
    <DefaultAuthenticatorConfig>SAMLSSOAuthenticator</DefaultAuthenticatorConfig>
    <ProvisioningConnectorConfigs>
    </ProvisioningConnectorConfigs>
    <DefaultProvisioningConnectorConfig/>
    <ClaimConfig>
        <LocalClaimDialect>false</LocalClaimDialect>
        <ClaimMappings>

            <ClaimMapping>
                <LocalClaim>
                        <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/userid</ClaimUri>
                </LocalClaim>
                <RemoteClaim>
                        <ClaimUri>uid</ClaimUri>
                </RemoteClaim>
                <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
            </ClaimMapping>

        </ClaimMappings>
    </ClaimConfig>
    <Certificate>MIID1T....mcrnA==</Certificate>
    <PermissionAndRoleConfig/>
    <JustInTimeProvisioningConfig>
            <UserStoreClaimUri/>
            <ProvisioningUserStore></ProvisioningUserStore>
            <IsProvisioningEnabled>false</IsProvisioningEnabled>
    </JustInTimeProvisioningConfig>
</IdentityProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's typo in the source code `IdentityApplicationConstants`, the correct parameter value should be `ISAuthnReqSigned`. This is an already known issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2720